# How to parse JSON with custom parameters using Codable protocol

Tags: json, swift, codable, decodable

I have a **JSON** with keys

```
{  
   "yearOfManufacture":"20/9/2018",
   "carSize":8,
   "isNew":true,
   "carAssets":[  
      {  
         "color":"5761807993001",
         "nativeId":"{\"app\":\"1234/Car/Native_App\",\"web\":\" /8888/Car/Native_Car_Desktop\"}"
      }
   ]
}
```

I am trying to parse using **Codable** protocol with struct models

```
struct Cars: Codable {
   var yearOfManufacture: String?
   var carSize: Int = 0
   var isNew: Bool = true
   var carAssets: [CarAssests]?
}

struct CarAssests: Codable { 
   var color: String?
   var nativeId: String?
}
```

I am getting error like **The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.** I  tried using CodingKeys with decoder container not getting the exact type of  **"nativeId": "{\"app\":\"1234/Car/Native_App\",\"web\":\" /8888/Car/Native_Car_Desktop\"}"** not getting exact data type of this.

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dataDecodingStrategy = .deferredToData
        if let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) {
            do {

                print(jsonData)
                let assets = try decoder.decode(Cars.self, from: jsonData)
                print(assets)
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "if i remove nativeId key" ?

Comment: if i remove nativeId  from JSON it is getting parsed successfully!!

Comment: nativeId is a JSON string, encoded as JSON. it wont be parsed in the same way, you will need to manually sort that one out

Comment: Do i need to encode complete JSON or only the key

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `jsonString`? Are you reading it from a file or using a multiline string literal?

Comment: using multiline string.

Comment: In a multiline string you have to escape all backslashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you are doing something like this:

```
let jsonString = """
{
"yearOfManufacture": "20/9/2018",
"carSize": 8,
"isNew": true,
"carAssets": [
{
"color": "5761807993001",
"nativeId": "{\"app\":\"1234/Car/Native_App\",\"web\":\" /8888/Car/Native_Car_Desktop\"}"
}
]
}
"""
```

In a multiline string, both `\"` and `"` mean the character `"`. So you have to write `\\"` to get the two characters `\` and `"`:

```
let jsonString = """
{
"yearOfManufacture": "20/9/2018",
"carSize": 8,
"isNew": true,
"carAssets": [
{
"color": "5761807993001",
"nativeId": "{\\"app\\":\\"1234/Car/Native_App\\",\\"web\\":\\" /8888/Car/Native_Car_Desktop\\"}"
}
]
}
"""
```

Comment: Yes this was the problem, how to solve same if we are getting from file or web service

Comment: @salmansiddiqui you don’t have to worry about it, assuming that the service formats their JSON properly. It’s only in string literals that you need to be careful to escape the characters.